# Create an installer for my game(.exe)

Tags: c++, windows, windows-installer, exe

I have built a bowling game in Glut C++ and have my .exe file.

Now I want to create an installer for this game.

What I want to do that:-

When my installer runs, *glut32.dll* is pasted inside *system32* folder and the .exe file of my game is on desktop or wherever.

How can I do this. *Iexpress* won't be able to do this I guess.

Note:- **glut32.dll** must be there in system32 folder to run this game.

Comment: do you want a self extracted installer or a full fledged msi install? It all depends on how much user interface you want to show and what parameters you wish to customize.

Comment: @AmitApollo I just want a way to paste glut32.dll file in system32 and the .exe file anywhere.

Comment: script an xcopy of the resource, then do the regsvr32 glut32.dll. You can do this with bat files command shell.

Comment: @AmitApollo I am using NSIS now. Can you tell how I can specify my desired directory after setOutPath?

Comment: @UmairAyub If you are using NSIS could you please respond to my answer? Can you elaborate on what you mean by desired directory?

Comment: I have got your answer @Derek that did for me. Now I am looking to change the icon of my exe file. Resource Hacker not working for me. When I open my bowlingGame.exe in Resource Hacker, none of any entry shows up. blank.

Comment: @Derek Can you please tell how to change the icon?

Comment: @UmairAyub Sure, but I would open another question if you cannot already find one here. I believe that deserves its own separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System)

Start by looking at the Simple Tutorials: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Simple_tutorials

They will show you how to simply copy a few files to a user's computer. Something like this:

```
# define the name of the installer
outfile "game_installer.exe"

# define the directory to install to
installDir $DESKTOP

# default section
section install

# define the output path for this file
setOutPath C:\Windows\System32

# define what to install and place it in the output path
File glut32.dll

# define the output path for this file
setOutPath $INSTDIR 

# define what to install and place it in the output path
File bowling_game.exe

sectionEnd
```

**Note**: Bartek Banachewicz and others are correct. You really shouldn't put non-system .dlls in a directory with all of your important system .dlls. The world isn't going to end because of it, but it isn't the best practice. Maybe you can work with NSIS to develop an installer that does what you want. Then I would recommend that you install the OpenGL/GLUT libraries/headers in a more appropriate location.

Answer (score 6):

Wrong. `glut32.dll` **DOES NOT** have to be in `system32`. It just has to be next to the `.exe` file. (Or somewhere in system `PATH`).

You should be able to create an installer that will unzip your files using InstallShield or similar wizard within your IDE.

Comment: system32 is also a valid location for dll's

Comment: Not really. Microsoft logo guidelines are against it for DLL hell reasons.

Comment: @Kevin I didn't say it is not. It doesn't contradict my statement.

Comment: "It just has to be next to the .exe file. (Or somewhere in system PATH)" implies these are the only possible spots. And @ChristopherPainter it does not matter if microsoft guidelines are against it, it's still a valid location.

Comment: @Kevin `system32` is in PATH